# Python - How can you plot a data histogram?

Tags: python, dataframe, histogram

I am looking to plot a date histogram. I have a pandas dataframe as follow:

```
Creation Date  Profile_ID Count
2016-06-01            150
2016-06-03            3
2016-06-04            20
```

How can I define the x and y axis of my histogram so that I have a plot of the number of newly-created profile ID per date?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = df.plot.bar(y='Profile_ID Count')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Importing the requisite libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Creating the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Creation Date':['2016-06-01','2016-06-03','2016-06-04'],'Profile_ID Count':[150,3,20]})

# Creating the bar chart below.
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(df['Creation Date'],df['Profile_ID Count'], color='red', width = 0.5)   
fig.autofmt_xdate()   # This tilts the dates displayed along X-axis.
ax.set_title('Creation Date vs. Profile ID Count')
ax.set_xlabel('Creation Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Profile ID Count')
plt.show()
```

[image: Bar-Chart]